# Scala: coding a different kind of Span function

Tags: scala

I want to code a scala function that works similarly to the [span](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.1/scala/List.html#span%28%28A%29%3D%3EBoolean%29) function but with a little trick: it returns the first list with all the increasing integers and the rest of the integers in the second list like so:

```
newSpan(List(2, 3, -1, 4, 7))
//> res1: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(2, 3),List(-1, 4, 7))
```

I thought about doing something simple like this:

```
l.span(x=> x < ?)
```

The problem is that I don't know how to determine if the next number will be higher than the previous.

Can anyone give me a hint please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val a = List(2,3,4,-5,4,5)
a.span(i=> a.sliding(2).takeWhile(l=> l.head<l.last).flatten.contains(i))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: Great solution, but I think the comparison operator `<` should be `<=` in order to cover cases like `List(2, 3, 3, 4, -1, 4, 7)`.  i.e. `l.span(i => l.sliding(2).takeWhile(l => l.head <= l.last).flatten.contains(i))`.

Answer (score 1):

you can group (using zip) elems with the following elements

```
l.zip(l.drop(1)).filter { case(el1, el2) => el2 > el1 }
```

I think this may be a good starting point. Now you will probably need to do a `.takeWhile` to get the prefix or something like that

I'm sorry I'm not giving you an exact solution, but I'm not fully understanding what you want

> Note: List.span defined at http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.1/scala/List.html#span%28%28A%29%3D%3EBoolean%29

Comment: Shouldn't the `l.take(1)` be `l.drop(1)` (or just `l.tail`)? You can also use `.sliding(2)` to get the same result (except that `.sliding` gets you a `Iterator`, not a `List`).

Comment: @Marth yes, thanks! sometimes I confuse take and drop (I always check on the REPL). I was not aware of `sliding`

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
(0 until l.length).takeWhile(i => i == 0 || l(i-1) < l(i)).map(l)
// res37: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(2, 3)
```

If you want a tuple as result:

```
((0 until l.length).toList.
    span(i => i == 0 || l(i-1) < l(i))
    match { case (x, y) => (x.map(l), y.map(l)) })
// res61: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(2, 3),List(-1, 4, 7))
```

Comment: This seems to be a good solution, the problem is that the return values are different from what I want. How would you make this solution return (List[Int], List[Int])?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use `sliding(2)` and then you can use `span`